# About PhoneGap development

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

I am android native developer but new in phonegap cross platform. I am using eclipse IDE for development. 
How to anyalysis application performance? How to get app error logs.
Which option is good for test 1) On browser 2) Android/iOS device?
My development 70% done now but application not working good. Issues are as follow - 
1. Getting more time for UI rendering. Means opening new screen display white screens, blinking screen, showing some UI parts first after sometime show other UI.
2. Suggest me some UI related improvements according to speed.
3. Same code working good on iOS but on not good on android.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you would like to improve? Is you app a single page app or do you load different HTML files? Do you currently use any UI or JavaScript frameworks?

Comment: Hi! Your question seems a little too broad - please try to identify the bottlenecks in your code and try to always include code samples in your questions.

Comment: 1. Go through the [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) documentation. 2. Use some Javascript frameworks, I recommend Ionic with AngularJS.